# Unable to delete docker image of a running container using -f option

Tags: image, docker, containers

I tried to create a container using the following

```
docker run -it centos bash
```

and exited without killing it.

Now I'm trying to delete the centos image using its image ID.

```
docker rmi -f 0f3e07c0138f
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 0f3e07c0138f (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container a9eab034a426
```

On docker documentation [page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/), it says " You cannot remove an image of a running container unless you use the -f option." but still I'm unable to remove image using -f. What can be the explanation for this? Should there a correction in documentation?

Comment: The image provides most of the actual filesystem content for the container; why do you want to do this?  Is this a question about programming that you can attach some actual source code to?

Comment: @DavidMaze Container is an instantiation of image with separate R/W layer.
If the container is stopped and the image is deleted and the container will work if started again. 
What I'm asking is why can't we remove it while container is running?

Comment: @harindersingh Container is the top layer ( as you said writable layer ) on an image. It can't exist without other layers.  Still, it doesn't answer your question :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these results

```
$ sudo docker rmi centos
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference 
"centos" (must force) - container be8f69d76892 is using its referenced image 
0f3e07c0138f
$ sudo docker rmi -f 0f3e07c0138f
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 0f3e07c0138f (cannot be 
forced) - image is being used by running container be8f69d76892
$ sudo docker rmi -f centos
Untagged: centos:latest
Untagged: 
centos@sha256:f94c1d992c193b3dc09e297ffd54d8a4f1dc946c37cbeceb26d35ce1647f88d9
```

docker rmi -f option only works on image name if container is running, even then it just untag the image but the image remains there with "none" repo and tag. see

```
<none>   <none>       0f3e07c0138f        3 months ago        220MB
```

And when you will run

```
sudo docker ps
```

you will see that image id is there instead of the image name

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                
be8f69d76892        0f3e07c0138f
```

I have removed other info in this docker ps command's result.

Answer (score 7):

`a9eab034a426` container is using `centos` image. So, to remove `centos`, you need to stop and remove `a9eab034a426` container. Run the following lines.

```
docker stop a9eab034a426
docker rm a9eab034a426
docker rmi 0f3e07c0138f
```

Comment: The question is wrt to using -f option.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/ mentions "You cannot remove an image of a running container unless you use the -f option." so technically you should be able to remove image using -f even if container is running